# Why does not Run as work in Eclipse the first time?

Tags: eclipse

When I open Eclipse(Galileo) for Java (and even Java EE) when I try to run a java (or Eclipse) application for the first time using a shortcut Alt+Shift+X,J (or E) the application will not run until I use the menus. Have you observed same problem and therefore it is an Eclipse thing, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been recently reported ([bug 298303](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298303)), but was first seen with Eclipse 3.4 ([bug 218881](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218881)).

It won't be fixed just yet.

> The underlying problem is that the debug plugins are not loaded yet, so when you activate the action handler nothing happens (although the SDK does know about the key combination).

And it is a regression from Eclipse3.3

> > This is definitely a (very annoying) regression from 3.3. It was one of the
> >     first things I noticed when upgrading to 3.4.
>
> Yes, we fixed some bugs in 3.4 that were eagerly loading the debug plugins (amongst other plugins) ... but this facet of debug only works (at the moment) with the plugins loaded.